# Image annotation: Is it better to create one file per image or one big file for the whole dataset?

Tags: file, architecture, software-design

I'm developing an application that extracts some information for every image in a dataset of images, and store these data for future use. The problem I have is how to properly store these data. Is it better to create a single annotation file (I use JSON files) for each image in the dataset or to create a big unique file that contains all the extracted data?

The kind of information I'm extracting is similar from image to image but not equal. The dataset of images can be huge, >1milion images.

If relevant, I'm using Python on Linux or MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a single document (file or in a NoSQL database) per dataset.

If you have > 1 million images, single file per image will mean  > 1 million files/documents.

Not something that will be easy to manage or manipulate.

A single file/document is much easier to manage and search.

I'd also consider using a NoSQL database to store the JSON documents.

EDIT:

After considering the comments, I'd have to say that you might need to cut off a JSON file at a certain amount of data, resulting in a few files per dataset.

As for files getting corrupted that's a risk you run on any storage, even database files, that's why we have backups and replicas.

You can always run a NoSQL database locally, but again, this will need some computing resources.

Comment: Is there any side effect in handling huge text files (>1GB) ? In the worst case, what happen if the file get corrupted somehow?

Comment: No, provided you have enough RAM and processing power. If it's corrupted you will have to write a manual program or manually correct the JSON file. If you do however use a NoSQL document store, you have a myriad of backup/replication options so this kind of thing won't be an issue.

Comment: There's also the option of limiting a single JSON document to 100,000 results or so. This will mean you have multiple files per dataset, it will be a shitloads more manageable than one file per image.

Comment: I found another problematic related to JSON files, if I want to update/append some new data to my file, I have to rewrite the whole file. Unless I use the JSON in a non-standard way. A database can be definitely be useful here but I want to create a stand-alone app.

Comment: What kind of machines do you think your program will be running on?

Comment: On desktop/laptop machine. Internet access is not guaranteed.